# Filtering boolean and returning parent title

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

```
let chains: {
    keys: {
        "key1": {
            inStock: boolean;
        };
        "key2": {
            inStock: boolean;
        };
        "key3": {
            inStock: boolean;
        };
        "key4": {
            inStock: boolean;
        };
        "key5": {
            inStock: boolean;
        };
        ... 6 more ...;
        "key5": {
            ...;
        };
    };
    inStock: boolean;
}
```

I need to `chains.fitler(x=>x.inStock)` bool statement then return the specific key, i also want to add conditions to return all if none are true.

EX: `key1, key5 | inStock:true` `return key1,key5`

Comment: What? Please add a [mre] and explain where you got stuck while trying to fix this yourself.

Comment: `Object.entries` is useful here, do you know how to use it?

Comment: @Wyck No I do not, Can you give me an ex?

Comment: @Wyck when I tried   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(chains)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  } it would returne keys: [object Object]
inStock: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure how you want the input and output to be but you should get a bit closer with this implementation:

```
let chains = {
    keys: {
        "key1": {
            inStock: true
        },
        "key2": {
            inStock: true
        },
        "key3": {
            inStock: true
        },
        "key4": {
            inStock: true
        },
        "key5": {
            inStock: false
        }
    },
    inStock: true
}

const getInStockItems = (allKeys) => {
    const result = []
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(allKeys)) {
        if(value.inStock) result.push(key)
    }
    return result;
}

getInStockItems(chains.keys) // key1, key2, key3, key4 (not key5 since it's not in stock)
```

Comment: I can't pass in a key arg, I just need to filter the boolean and return the key if true

Comment: Oh, then it's just simpler. Remove the findKeys parameter and statement, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried but it's not working still

Comment: I've updated my answer with the changes.

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as the accepted answer if you are satisfied with the solution.